# Как выбрать все поля из таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы А и Б. Из таблицы А выбираю все значения, но с Б только поле логин например. Как это сделать? Пока у меня получается только выборка всех значений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT A.*, B.login FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.fid;`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT A.* - плохая практика. лучше перечислить Все необходимые поля.

**Обновление**

Я тоже раньше так думал, пока не набрел на одну статейку (она даже вроде на харбе есть). Объяснение следующее:
Допустим, ты разрабатываешь программу, и в данный текущий момент тебе действительно нужны все поля. Разработка идет своим ходом, и много где в своем коде ты написал `SELECT A.*`. И тут вдруг ты добавляешь поля к таблице  - и не дай бог ТИПА TEXT. И получается, что там, где раньше было `SELECT A.**`, на самом деле уже НЕ НУЖНО ВСЕ ПОЛЯ (с учетом добавленных полей) - и тут начинаются тормоза. И еще это может усугубится тем, что кто-то начал дорабатывать после тебя твой проект.

Comment: С чего это вдруг? Зачем мне перечислять поля, когда мне нужны они все?